# jQuery ajax redirect

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect

Guys i have a little problem when i submit my form the page gets redirected to the result, instead of staying on the same page. On the server-side i have a PHP that spits an simple status codes like this:

```
echo '<span>Success/Error</span>';
exit;
```

and this is my request:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
   alert('Transmitted, but no result');
  },
  error: function() {
   alert('NOT sended');
  }
 });
```

the form itself its simple:

```
echo '<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
```

And btw can someone help me out why the success/error functions are not called?

Comment: It sounds like you're getting a JavaScript error somewhere (and the default action is happening), can you check your console?  Also what is `dataString`?

Comment: No console errors, atleast Firebug doesn't show a thing.

Comment: What's triggering the AJAX request? Is there an `onsubmit` event attached to the form or something?

Comment: @Anonymous - Can you post your full handler? I presume this `$.ajax()` call it inside a `submit` handler (please post whatever it's in), are you returning `false` or preventing the default action otherwise?

Comment: Yeah its called from a submit event:

jQuery('#submitForm').submit();

it returns false, but still i get redirected

Comment: The error will only be called if the response IS an error, a 400 or a 500 error code? Likewise, success will only be called if a success code is received, a 200 or 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanted to use [this](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Answer (score -1):

Remove the method from the form tag

Comment: 1. The attribute is required. 2. Removing it would just cause the form to submit to the current URI as browsers error recover. 3. The question clearly shows that it is missing already.

Comment: No actually its not missing its there, i tried without it and as you say its transformed to a GET request.

Comment: The browser treats request from the HTML form and JS XHT request as two separate entities, which is correct. If you're sending an ajax request as post with dataString variables, the html form element has NOTHING to do with this.

Comment: Okay what can i do to fix this? I mean now i try serializing the data for the POST request.